# Clear All TextBoxes when Input is changed in a certain box in WinForm program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application where the user enters their name and weight and it will convert the weight. I was wondering if there was a way that if the user's name input was less than 2 characters the 'calculate' button would be disabled and would re-enable when more than 2 characters. I am required to create an isValid method and when I run it my application does not disable the button.

```
public bool isValid (String text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name.Text) || Name.Text.Length < 2)
        {
            return false; 
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
   private void ValidateName()
    {

        while (isValid(Name.Text) == false)
        {
            this.ConvertBtn.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [TextChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    this.ValidateName(myTextBox.text);
}
```

In this case `IsValid` method will be executed when any changes happened in the `TextBox`.

I think in your case [Leave Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave(v=vs.110).aspx) will be better since it will execute only when user leave a control

```
private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myTextBox = (TextBox)sender;
    this.ValidateName(myTextBox.text);
}
```

And change your `IsValid` method to use parameter passed there

```
public bool isValid (String text)
{
    cosnt int MIN_LENGTH = 2;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) == true) return false;
    if (text.Length < MIN_LENGTH) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Then you don't need a loop in the `Validate` method

```
private void ValidateName(string name)
{
    this.ConvertBtn.Enabled = this.IsValid(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use textChanged event of textbox in which name is input. From that event, you can call isValid method

Comment: Okay thanks! It worked, however, now when I type something my convert button is disabled and I can no longer type any other characters. (I can only type the first character)

Comment: @MalloryRich, remove your `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Added trim() to Name.Text as scenario might be Name should not include pre and post spaces. If its no required you can remove the trim().

```
const int LENGTH_MIN_NAME = 2;
private void Name_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ConvertBtn.Enabled = isValid(Name.Text.Trim());
}

public bool isValid(String text)
{
    return (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text) ||  text.Length <= LENGTH_MIN_NAME));
}
```